# How to write a std::function with lambda expression in a map container using C#?

Tags: c#, c++, lambda, delegates, std-function

How would I rewrite the below C++ code into C#?

```
std::string someVariable;

std::map<std::string, std::function<void (std::string)>> myMap;

myMap.insert(std::make_pair("someText", [&](std::string input){someVariable = input;});
```

I have tried playing with delegates but I am not quite understanding it yet.

Comment: Your lambda in c# would look like this: `(string input) => { someVariable = input; }` or for brevity `(x) => someVariable = x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to do it like this but here's the equivalent C# code:

```
string someVariable = string.Empty;

Dictionary<string, Action<string>> map = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>();

map.Add("someText", (input) => someVariable = input);

map["someText"]("someInput");

Console.WriteLine(someVariable);
```

Output:

```
someInput
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/03sbqH

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! i will try this out.